# Submit a request parameter through an HTML hidden field, when a form is partially processed and submitted

Tags: jsf, hidden-field

I need to submit a view based random token to identify a WebSocket channel.

The bean that generates a `UUID` value.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SocketTokenBean implements Serializable {

    private String token; // Getter & setter.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SocketTokenBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

The token is submitted using an `<h:inputHidden>` as follows.

```
<h:inputHidden id="socketToken" value="#{socketTokenBean.token}"/>

<p:commandButton partialSubmit="true"
                 process="@this socketToken"
                 value="Submit"
                 actionListener="#{targetBean.action}"/>
```

Here, using `<input type="hidden">` is not possible as the form is partially processed and submitted. (It would have been much better, otherwise).

This field value is retrieved by using `context.getRequestParameterMap().get("form:socketToken")`. This is repeated in a few beans out of 200+ beans approximately. In this case, a small but a maintainability problem occurs, when the `id` of the associated `<h:form>` is changed to something different which makes it compulsory to make this change to all associated managed beans manually.

This also requires a setter method in `SocketTokenBean`. This means that one can easily set a different random value to the `token` bean property.

Is it possible to use a plain HTML element `<input type="hidden">`, when `partialSubmit` is set to `true` (though does not seem feasible)?

Or is there another similar way that simulates the same as `<input type="hidden">` so that its value can be retrieved just by `socketToken` (thus not `form:socketToken`)?

<sub>Setting `prependId` to `false` is not a solution as obvious.</sub>

Comment: Technically a nice question, but as to the concrete functional requirement, why do you want to pass back the token if you already have it in a view scoped bean which you could just `@Inject` in other beans?

Comment: This requires injecting a view scoped bean (i.e `SocketTokenBean`) into an application scoped bean (holding CDI observers). I did not test this but I feel it will not work reliably as the token arrives from different views (JSF pages) with a different / separate token. I assumed it would be possible to submit a request parameter in the form of `<input type="hidden">` in the same way as the JSF framework itself submits the `javax.faces.ViewState` hidden field to identify uniquely a specific component tree stored in an HTTP session, even though a form is partially processed and submitted.

Comment: I will edit the question, if needed.

Comment: If beans are managed by CDI, injecting from a smaller scope is not a problem. They are injected are proxies. As to the concrete question, yes I already understood you, I was only holding off because there's a simpler solution.

Comment: I see injecting a view scoped bean into an application scoped bean gives the correct desired token every time an action is executed through different views.